# How can I automate my webpack build to auto escape data URIs in SASS and HTML files?

Tags: svg, webpack, css-loader, raw-loader

The issue I am facing is that firefox does not support `#` characters in data URIs. Chrome or Safari are totally fine with this.

Our UI guys have used a lot of inlining of SVGs and these all contain data URIS

for example in `scss` files:

```
content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...</svg>');
```

and in `html` files:

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="234px" height="205px"...</svg>'>
```

And there are 100s of examples like this and none of these work in firefox because they have `#` character and I get the following error

[image: Firefox error]

but when we try `%23` in place of that character, the SVGs load correctly.

How can I automate the build so that these get url encoded.

The string replace has to extremely specific and needs to do it only inside `img` tags in html and `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8` in less files.

This is what I am thinking of doing: find all `stroke="#`  and replace with `stroke='%23` and same thing with `fill` if harder to do with webpack